# How to set existing component name dynamically in Swing

Tags: java, swing

i'm java beginner ...here i want to change name of existing component in java swings dynamically

```
import javax.swing.*;    
class DemoForm extends JFrame


{
JPanel mainpane=new JPanel();     
JTextField txtfld=new JTextField(5);    
DemoForm()    
{    
// if first_name is string literal type
    //here i want to change txtfld to first_Name    
    //is there any mechanism toconvert txtfld to first_name
    mainpane.add(first_name);
    this.add(mainpane);    
    this.setVisible(true);    
    this.setSize(400,500);  
}   
public static void main(String args[])    
{   
    new DemoForm();
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
import javax.swing.*;    
class DemoForm extends JFrame


{
JPanel mainpane=new JPanel();     
JTextField txtfld=new JTextField(5);    
DemoForm()    
{    
    //here i want to change txtfld to first_Name    
    //is there any mechanism toconvert txtfld to first_name
    JTextField first_name = txtfld ; 
    mainpane.add(first_name);
    this.add(mainpane);    
    this.setVisible(true);    
    this.setSize(400,500);  
}   
public static void main(String args[])    
{   
    new DemoForm();
}   
}
```

that mean first_name is point to the txtfld

Comment: first_name is string type not a JTextField type ? what do i do now?

Comment: i am not sure what you want but if you mean that you need Label then the following code will help you
JLabel first_name = new JLabel(); first_name.setText(txtfId.getText()) ;
not sure what you mean by String String can not add it to the container but it can be drawn to it or it can  bounded to label.

Comment: not exactly ,,here i'm giving detailed explanation:: my task is,,if i enter a string from keyboard...corresponding textfield has to be generated which is named as the string(given from keyboard) ..help me to solve?

Comment: ok , in this case you need ActionListenr on the txtfId, in that action you need to do the following 1- read the user input 2- use java reflection to create JTextField with the name of what ever the user enter in the txtfId then get the container and add the new JTextfield to it, this is the only way to do it.

Answer (score -3):

Are you using an IDE??
NetBeans has a swing design interface where you drag and drop anything you want into the pane. You can change any display you want from there.

Comment: yeah...you are right but in my task,there is need ,that helps me to reduce code.. let me summarize my task::  my aim is,,if i enter a string from keyboard...corresponding textfield has to be generated which is named as the string(given from keyboard) ..help me to solve